# Unable to click element after frame switch in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element after switching to a frame. Switch works fine. But element is not clickable. There are 2 iframes in the page. I need to click an element present under second iframe. So switched to it and tried to click the element.

NOTE: Same code without any changes works fine sometimes. It is inconsistent. Do not know what is the reason? If same code works fine once, then why cannot always? and I am using static locator value for frame. So there is no change in its locator value.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to below reasons,

1) Could be frame is loading late , try to print logs before and after switching frame

Comment: I have added print statements before and after frame switch. They work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void switchToVideoIframe() throws Exception {

    WebElement hoverOnWindow = getWebElement("cz.body");

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(hoverOnWindow).perform();
    System.out.println("Hover on Player");

//  util.driverwait(3);

    WebElement onPlayer = getWebElement("cz.player");
    driver.switchTo().frame(onPlayer);



    System.out.println("Switch on Player");
    util.driverwait(5);

}
```

Try with this approach

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks